# Android 2.2 and 2.3 PDF download via HTTPS seems broken

Tags: android, pdf, https, webkit, download

I've been going nuts about PDF downloads to mobile devices. Here's the next madness, observable on Android 2.2 and 2.3. I couldn't reproduce this problem on iPhones or other devices, neither on Firefox or other desktop browsers.

I'm downloading a PDF via HTTP and it works just fine. Then I'm downloading the same PDF via HTTPS and the download doesn't finish (and the filename is lost):

[image: Download doesn't finish and filename is lost]

I'm using these HTTP headers (and others, which are irrelevant here):

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="abc.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

Changing the `Content-Disposition` to `inline` or removing it entirely doesn't help either. Removing the `Content-Type` will results in displaying the raw binary data in the browser window.

Note: I've already discovered [a problem related to untrusted SSL certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9376445/521799), but that doesn't seem to be the only problem. So I'm really looking for yet another explanation.

Any ideas welcome!

Comment: A certificate is trusted if the signer is trusted. Are the trusted Root authorizers of the certifcate trusted by the device?

Comment: I mentioned in the answer that the certificate is not trusted. But this shouldn't matter as a) the user may accept untrusted certificates explicitly, and b) this should not impact downloads

Comment: Any further information on this issue? I am experiencing the exact same problem when downloading a PDF file, via HTTPS, and it is only manifested in browsers that use the android download manager (native browser, Dolphin browser). I have tried various different content-types, including aplication/octet-stream and aplication/pdf.

Comment: @BojanaPopovska: Unfortunately, I haven't heard much in the direction of a fix on the two tickets I mentioned in my answer. You can add your comments there, maybe with reproduction instructions, and hope for the best!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As always, after some hard looking there is an ancient bug report on google code with lots of frustrated developer comments... Here are two open issues related to this problem:

- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3492
- http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5851

It seems that downloading PDFs using SSL with untrusted certificates (which is the case in my test environment) doesn't work with exactly the symptoms that I have mentioned

**Update**: That is only *one* problem. But it doesn't seem to be the only one

**Update**: As a matter of fact, here is some authoritative information on the whole matter, showing that at the time, `Content-Disposition` was poorly implemented *and specified*, which explains many problems encountered when implementing downloads over HTTP:

http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231

Answer (score 0):

Unable to test this right now as I don't have an https server running anywhere convenient, but does sending `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` with the headers make any difference?

Obviously, based on your situation and requirements, this may not be an option. Beyond that, try with a valid SSL certificate!

Comment: Hello. As I mentioned, the validity of the SSL certificate doesn't seem to be the only issue. And I've tried all sorts of `Content-Type`, including the one you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Besides the certificate validity, the order of the CA chain is also important for the Android download manager to be able to download files.

In order to make sure the intermediate certificates are in the proper order, you can run the following command:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.google.ch:443 -showcerts | grep ":/[C1]"
```

This should return a nicely ordered chain such as:

```
0) subject: server
   issuer:  ca1
1) subject: ca1
   issuer:  ca2
2) subject: ca2
   issuer:  ca3
```

And not something like this:

```
0) subject: server
   issuer:  ca1
1) subject: ca2
   issuer:  ca3
2) subject: ca1
   issuer:  ca2
```