# Can't save PDF from browser if under HTTPS

Tags: https, http-headers, content-type, content-disposition

I have a page which outputs a PDF file to the browser, and sets the following headers:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="myFile.pdf"
```

So, the file should be viewed in the browser rather than downloading. This works as expected in Chrome for desktop, except that the "Save" button in the bottom right corner doesn't do anything.

Additionally, when opening on a mobile (where the file is automatically downloaded), the download fails as the file is `<Untitled>` - despite the presence of `filename="myFile.pdf` in the headers.

I thought this was a header issue, but have narrowed it down to the fact the page is under HTTPS. If I open the page under HTTP then everything works as expected (files saved successfully) on both desktop and mobile.

So, is there any way to get this working under HTTPS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 2.2 and 2.3 PDF download via HTTPS seems broken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375997/android-2-2-and-2-3-pdf-download-via-https-seems-broken)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue is due to the SSL certificate under which the website is hosted being invalid.

See more here - [Android 2.2 and 2.3 PDF download via HTTPS seems broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375997/android-2-2-and-2-3-pdf-download-via-https-seems-broken)